# Facebook pop up goes blank in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I am facing this strange issue in case when user taps on FBConnect button the facebook pop up does appear shows a message "Connect to Facebook" but after few seconds the pop-up goes blank. Please refer the image for more details. I have tried to log the error and enabled break-points over the error delegate methods but control never reaches to those methods. I have never faced this issue before and everything seems to be working fine but now out of the blue this issue came. Initially I thought that the API key got expired, hence change the same but it didn't fix the problem. 
[image: Facebook pop up issue]

Comment: it looks to me like a network problem where the connection does not time out.

Comment: @JeanLuc I believe its more of a Facebook SDK issue, the version which I was using earlier is obsolete now, therefore updated the same and the problem seems to be disappeared now.

Comment: Sandy - can you please explain exactly wht you did to update the SDK? I am trying to add FacebookAgent that uses FBConnect library and I have the same problem. If I try to add the new FB SDK as a framework, I get linker errors with FBConnect. If I use FBConnect without the SDK framework, it builds but I get that blank screen. Please explain what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: @sandy yes the facebook sdk wasn't handling it correctly

Comment: @Marc Please refer facebook tutorial for integrating the latest SDK in your app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ sample Scrumptious app will help you understand the integration process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by updating my Facebook SDK to version 3.0. Previous version of this SDK are obsolete now.